# How to add text at the bottom of each flexbox

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a flexbox container with 4 flex items. I need output like the image below

[image]

I have done the coding part but I am stuck with adding the text below the flexbox

My Code:

```
.flex-container {
  margin: 40px auto 0 auto;
  margin-top: 0;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  background-color: white;
  
}

.flex-container > div {
  margin: 40px auto 0 auto;
  color: white;
  background-color:lightgray;
  width: 140px;
  margin: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 140px;
  font-size: 20px;
  
}

<body>

<div class="flex-container">
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div> 
  <div>4</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Where's the html code for the text at the bottom?

Answer (score 2):

This is how I would do it.

```css
.flex-container {
  margin: 40px auto 0 auto;
  margin-top: 0;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  background-color: white;
  
}

.box {
  margin: 40px auto 0 auto;
  color: white;
  background-color:lightgray;
  width: 140px;
  margin: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 140px;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.text{
  text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="box">1</div>
    <div class="text">BOX1</div>
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="box">2</div>
    <div class="text">BOX2</div>
  </div>
   <div class="container">
   <div class="box">3</div> 
     <div class="text">BOX3</div>
  </div>
   <div class="container">
   <div class="box">4</div>
     <div class="text">BOX4</div>
  </div>
  
</div>
```

Comment: Dear Paria, please provide at least a simple explanation about your solution. Although I vote up for your answer, please check this link: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer Good Luck.

Comment: Thank you so much for voting. I'll keep this in mind from now on.

Answer (score 0):

Simply do this:
**(The more appropriate way to do it with table)**

```css
.box{
   background-color: #7c7cab;
   height: 80px;
   display: flex;
   margin: 10px;
   color: white;
}

.box,.textbox{
   width: 20%;
   float: left;
}

.textbox{
   color: black;
   margin-left: 10px;
   margin-right: 10px;
   text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="boxes">
      <div class="box">box 1</div>
      <div class="box">box 2</div>
      <div class="box">box 3</div>
      <div class="box">box 4</div>
</div>
<div class="text-box">
      <div class="textbox">text 1</div>
      <div class="textbox">text 2</div>
      <div class="textbox">text 3</div>
      <div class="textbox">text 4</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Hopefully this works for you.

```css
.flex-container {
  margin: 40px auto 0 auto;
  margin-top: 0;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  background-color: white;
  text-align: center;
}

.container {
  margin: 40px auto 0 auto;
  color: white;
  background-color:lightgray;
  width: 140px;
  margin: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 140px;
  font-size: 20px;
  
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
  <div>
    <div class='container'>1</div>
    <span>Box 1</span>
  </div>
  <div>
  <div class='container'>1</div>
    <span>Box 2</span>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div class='container'>1</div>
    <span>Box 3</span>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div class='container'>1</div>
    <span>Box 4</span>
  </div>
</div>
```